# What is the proper, pythonic way to apply some properties of one nested dictionary to another?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have this nested dict:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mammals",
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Chinchilla",
            "extinct": False
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Wooly Mammoth",
            "extinct": True
        },
        ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

But Oh No! The Chinchilla has gone extinct! Now I have another, smaller, dict of identical format which represents updates to the `extinct` value on one or more members:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mammals",
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Chinchilla",
            "extinct": True
        },
        ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I could start nesting `for` loops, throw in an `if` or two to compare `id` values, and tackle this pretty easily - but that many layers of nesting just *feels* bad to do. Is there a better and/or more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Not really. Unless you want to use a library which contains all the nested loops and comparisons and provides a different API.

Comment: Nested for's is pretty reasonable here. If you plan to make multiple updates, then indexing the nested dict once and doing a shorter index based lookup is reasonable. Or change the format. This could be stored in a database or perhaps even loaded into a pandas table after flattening .

Comment: I would start by thinking if it made sense to turn this into one large dictionary rather than lists of lists.

Comment: You could convert that outer list into a dict whose key is each entry's id. Then do the same with each animals list. Now lookup is by id.

Comment: Sort of related: [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](/q/3232943/4518341)

Comment: "but that many layers of nesting just feels bad to do." *but that is an issue with your data as it exists*. If you want to keep this format, then this is what you need to do. That isn't to say you couldn't change the way your data is organized.

Comment: The [glom](https://pypi.org/project/glom) package was written to address exactly the needs you describe.